# Populate text box based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this javascript function hoping to populate a textbox based on drop down selection. I am just using the first option (there are 7 more options, but this should illustrate the issue):

```
<script>
function TicketsQuantity(){
  if (document.getElementByID("RaffleDollars").value == 25){
    (document.getElementById("RaffleTickets").value = "1");
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the drop down box code:

```
<select size="1" name="RaffleDollars" id="RaffleDollars" 
onChange="javascript:TicketsQuantity();">               
<option selected value="0.00">------Select $ Amount------</option>
<option value="25">25.00</option>
</select>
```

Here is the text box code:

```
<input name="RaffleTickets" size="5" id="RaffleTickets">
```

When I select 25.00 from the drop down box, it is not populating textbox with 1.  Is my syntax incorrect? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have an error: `getElementByID` is incorrect. Change it to: `getElementById`.

Please correct your code to use the below. Remove `javascript:` here:

```
onChange="TicketsQuantity();"
```

Since you are using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), I would give you a jQuery based solution:

```
$(function () {
  $("#RaffleDollars").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "25")
      $("#RaffleTickets").val("1");
  });
});
```

**Working Snippet**

```html
<select size="1" name="RaffleDollars" id="RaffleDollars" onChange="TicketsQuantity();">
  <option selected value="0.00">------Select $ Amount------</option>
  <option value="25">25.00</option>
</select>
<input name="RaffleTickets" size="5" id="RaffleTickets">
<script>
  function TicketsQuantity() {
    if (document.getElementById("RaffleDollars").value == 25) {
      document.getElementById("RaffleTickets").value = "1";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @cdr6800 You have an error: `getElementByID` is incorrect. Change it to: `getElementById`.

Comment: Sorry Praveen...I did not see your entire answer. I will try it now.

Comment: Praveen...what if I wanted to fill another text box with something different based on the same drop down selection? For example, I also want to fill another textbox (id is Total_Raffle) with 25.00. I tried this, but it did not work:

    $(function () {
      $("#RaffleDollars").change(function () {
         if ($(this).val() == "25")
          $("#RaffleTickets").val("1");
          $("#Total_Raffle").val("25");
      });
    });

Thanks...
David

Comment: Sorry, formatting was bad

$(function () {
  $("#RaffleDollars").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "25")
      $("#RaffleTickets").val("1");
      $("#Total_Raffle").val("25");
  });
});

Comment: OK, figured it out. Looks like I need to do a whole separate function. Thanks

Comment: Another question, on the second function to populate the second text box , how would I make it show 2 decimal points? Here is the code:

Comment: I would like the Total_Raffle textbox to show 25.00 instead of just 25

$(function () {
  $("#RaffleDollars").change(function () {
     if ($(this).val() == "25")
      $("#Total_Raffle").val(25);

Comment: @cdr6800 You can use `$("#Total_Raffle").val($(this).val())`.